# MERGE vs. UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, merge, sql-update

I was trying to look for it online but couldn't find anything that will settle my doubts.

I want to figure out which one is better to use, when and why?

I know MERGE is usually used for an upsert, but there are some cases that a normal update with with subquery has to select twice from the table(one from a where clause).

E.G.:

```
MERGE INTO TableA s
USING (SELECT sd.dwh_key,sd.serial_number from TableA@to_devstg sd
       where sd.dwh_key = s.dwh_key and sd.serial_number <> s.serial_number) t
ON(s.dwh_key = t.dwh_key)
WHEN MATCHED UPDATE SET s.serial_number = t.serial_number
```

In my case, i have to update a table with about 200mil records in one enviorment, based on the same table from another enviorment where change has happen on serial_number field. As you can see, it select onces from this huge table.

On the other hand, I can use an UPDATE STATEMENT like this:

```
UPDATE TableA s
SET s.serial_number = (SELECT t.serial_number
                       FROM TableA@to_Other t
                       WHERE t.dwh_serial_key = s.dwh_serial_key)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableA@To_Other t
              WHERE t.dwh_serial_key = s.dwh_serial_key
              AND t.serial_number <> s.serial_number)
```

As you can see, this select from the huge table twice now. So, my question is, what is better? why?.. which cases one will be better than the other..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you fix that update (go with join table on itself) and then check speed / execution plan?

Comment: @Veljko89 and how would I do that in oracle?

Comment: Not working much with oracle but im sure there is inner join in it ... I could try to write it down, gimme few min

Comment: @Veljko89 this is the syntax for an update with join in oracle

Comment: Damn that syntax sucks ... just googled it ... Oracle does not support joins in the UPDATE statements. ... you learn something new every day!

Comment: Yea I know, thats why I posted my question:) @Veljko89

Comment: I would tend to use UPDATE for simple updates (by which I mean either the whole table is being updated, or some subsection that doesn't need a subquery to filter the rows - eg. `update table_name set ... where col1 = 'some value';`) and I would use MERGE for upserts and updates that have joins in them which would require running the same subquery effectively twice. It's not a hard and fast rule though, as it depends on table sizes, query complexity, required performance, etc. MERGE statements can be easier to read and understand, however, meaning they can be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first try to load all necessary data from remote DB to the temporary table and then work with that temporary table.

```
create global temporary table tmp_stage (
    dwh_key         <your_dwh_key_type@to_devstg>,
    serial_number   <your_serial_number_type@@to_devstg>
) on commit preserve rows;

insert into tmp_stage
select dwh_key, serial_number
from TableA@to_devstg sd
where sd.dwh_key = s.dwh_key;


/* index (PK on dwh_key) your temporary table if necessary ...*/

update (select
         src.dwh_key src_key,
         tgt.dwh_key tgt_key,
         src.serial_number src_serial_number,
         tgt.serial_number tgt_serial_number
       from tmp_stage src
       join TableA tgt
         on src.dwh_key = tgt.dwh_key
       )
  set src_serial_number = tgt_serial_number;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd already thought about using a temporary table storing all the diffrences between those two tables.. I posted my question to figure out which one is better, MERGE or UPDATE. So U'd say update will be faster then a merge here? why?

Comment: @sagi, just test and compare both approaches on a smaller data set with the same indexes... ;)

Comment: That is what I'm going to do:) I also want to try another approach will a loop (for rec in(....using Oracle's Rownum) . I just asked if there's some rules about it and times that it will be faster to merge / update.. anyway i'll upvote your answer but that still doesn't answer my question

Comment: well, i'm not 100% sure, but i think update should be bit faster.

Comment: sometimes it's easier/faster to refactor (create new table with needed values) the whole table instead of updating 200 mio. rows.